# PHP web service messages truncated by output buffering

Tags: php, web-services, soap, output-buffering

I'm developing a web service on PHP where I use the standard PHP SoapServer class with a WSDL file provided by my client, but I also need to use output buffering to "tidy up" the SOAP response that PHP produces (adding some missing namespaces, adding `xmlns=""` to a few tags and other small but necessary details).
The problem is that when I use explicit output buffering (`ob_start()`, `ob_end_flush()` ...), any outbound message from my server gets truncated, whatever its size (I'm testing in the range of about 2KB-50KB). When I don't use explicit output buffering, the client gets the complete SOAP response, but as those details I mentioned haven't been fixed, the format isn't quite right.
Here's the code of my server:

```
if (!extension_loaded("soap")) {
    dl("php_soap.dll");
}

//Disable wsdl caching
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

//Get SOAP message from client
$input_msg = file_get_contents("php://input");

//Create SoapServer object with url to the .wsdl file
$server = new SoapServer(WSDL_FILE_URL, array('encoding' => 'UTF-8', 'actor' => SERVER_URL));

//Set the class that will handle every possible request form the client
$server->setClass("ServerHandler",$input_msg);

//Before I let the server handle the request and return the response to the client,
//I turn on output buffering so I can fix its format
ob_start(NULL, 1<<20);
$server->handle(); //let the server handle the request and write the response to the buffer
$soapXml = ob_get_contents(); //I get the response from the output buffer
ob_end_clean(); //clear the output buffer of its content

//this function does all those small format fixes to the SOAP response that PHP produces
$soapXml=fixSoapResponseFormat($soapXml);

echo $soapXml;//put the correct SOAP response in the output buffer
ob_end_flush();//flush the output buffer and turn off buffering
flush();//this supossedly flushes lower level buffers, just in case
```

As you can see, I've tried using a high value for the `$chunk_size` parameter of `ob_start()`, and adding `flush()` after `ob_end_flush()`, just in case. I've also tried setting `output_buffering = On` on php.ini (which supposedly enables an unlimited output buffer) and setting `LimitRequestFieldSize` and `LimitRequestLine` to 5500000 on Apache, but to no avail.
I've tried dumping to disk the contents of `$soapXml` after flushing the buffer, and the message is complete, so I guess the problem must be in the `echo $soapXml;` line or in the flushing of the buffer right after it.
I'm using Apache with PHP 5.3 to run the server and SoapUI 5 as a client to test it. I'm also using WS-Security in all communications between server and client (in case it's relevant).

Does anyone know how to solve this problem with the buffering of SOAP messages? Maybe there's another way to catch and modify the SOAP response that PHP produces before it's sent to the client? I'd be grateful for any advice.

Comment: Where are you outputting $soapXml? Right to the browser? Or is it a CLI application?

Comment: I'm outputting "right to the browser" so to speak, but it's really a client program (SoapUI). My server program gets a SOAP request from the client via http and returns a response via http also. That response is the output I'm having trouble with.

Comment: Probably, the browser displays xml tags improperly and you don't escape them. You said that you successfully dumped the document to the disk. Have you tried to open the page source code?

Comment: That's a good sugestion, but I don't think that's the problem here, because SoapUI is not exactly a browser and is supposed to display unescaped XML properly. As a matter of fact, when I don't use output buffering, SoapUI gets the complete XML message and displays it properly, without me escaping anything. Anyway, I'll try to build my own quick client program to test the server and dump the response to disk, just in case.

Comment: Just in case it's not clear, I've successfully dumped the message (`$soapXml`) to disk **in the server**, which means that the data is supposedly complete before it gets written to the output buffer, at least.

Comment: Then I suspect that there is something wrong with fixSoapResponseFormat. Can you post it here?

Comment: Mmm... this is really weird. If I remove the `$soapXml=fixSoapResponseFormat($soapXml);` line, the message is sent properly. However, if I keep that line, the message is sent truncated, but if I dump it to disk in the server just after sending it, it is complete and properly modified by `fixSoapResponseFormat()`! That function consists of just a loop where I do a series of substitutions in the message with `$soapXml=str_replace($original_tag, $replacement_tag, $soapXml);`. I always replace whole XML tags with their more complete equivalents, to avoid unwanted substitutions.

Comment: Well, that's it. If you can post your implementation here, we'll come to a better/reliable solution.

Comment: Ok, I've finally found the problem: The http header for the response was generated in the `$server->handle();` line, and when I called `fixSoapResponseFormat()` the message got larger but I didn't update the size data in the header. I'll post the working code as an answer, so people can find it easily. Thanks a lot for putting me on the right track, Valentin! Anything I can do to improve your reputation? (I'm new to this site)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the problem was that I was letting PHP generate a SOAP message with its http header in the `$server->handle();` line, but then I was capturing it in the buffer and **changing its size without updating the `Content-Length` http header**, so the message was sent, but got truncated to its original size.
So here's the properly working code:

```
if (!extension_loaded("soap")) {
    dl("php_soap.dll");
}

//Disable wsdl caching
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

//Get SOAP message from client
$input_msg = file_get_contents("php://input");

//Create SoapServer object with url to the .wsdl file
$server = new SoapServer(WSDL_FILE_URL, array('encoding' => 'UTF-8', 'actor' => SERVER_URL));

//Set the class that will handle every possible request form the client
$server->setClass("ServerHandler",$input_msg);

//Before I let the server handle the request and return the response to the client,
//I turn on output buffering so I can fix its format
ob_start(NULL, 1<<20);
$server->handle(); //let the server handle the request and write the response to the buffer
$soapXml = ob_get_contents(); //I get the response from the output buffer
ob_end_clean(); //clear the output buffer of its content

//this function does all those small format fixes to the SOAP response that PHP produces
$soapXml=fixSoapResponseFormat($soapXml);

header('Content-Length: '.strlen($soapXml));//**UPDATE THE LENGTH HEADER**

echo $soapXml;//put the correct SOAP response in the output buffer
ob_end_flush();//flush the output buffer and turn off buffering
flush();//this supossedly flushes lower level buffers, just in case
```

Many thanks to Valentin Rodygin for his great help in finding the source of my troubles!